# Material UI: use media query outside component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on React app with [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/).

Is there any way to use media query or determine viewport width in React/Material-UI way outside a component body?

I need to set default props for a component based on viewport size.

For now, I am handling it with `windows.innerWidth` as below.

```
const defaultProps = {
  textVariant: window.innerWidth < 600 ? 'body1' : 'h4',
}

const Text = (props)  => {
    ...
}

Text.defaultProps = defaultProps;
```

Is there any Material-UI utility that can be used in setting default props based on viewport size?

Comment: i know about `react-use`. `import { useWindowSize } from 'react-use';`  `const windowSize = useWindowSize();`  `windowSize.width < val`

Comment: `useWindowSize()` sounds like a hook. If it is the case, I don't think it can be used outside a component. Please correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. window width can be changed when you resize the browser window, putting the code outside like that will compute the `textVariant` value at compile time. while using `useMediaQuery` or [`useWindowSize`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/8ceb4c0f0c5625124f487b435a2fd0d3b3bc2a4f/src/useWindowSize.ts#L21-L24) will listen to the `resize` event and give you the correct `width` value at runtime.

What you can do instead is to store the default value as a state and update that value when the window size changes. Below is the minimal example:

```js
function useVariant(variant?: Variant) {
  const [defaultVariant, setDefaultVariant] = useState<Variant>("h6");
  const largeScreen = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (largeScreen) {
      setDefaultVariant("h5");
    } else {
      setDefaultVariant("h6");
    }
  }, [largeScreen]);

  return variant || defaultVariant;
}

export default function Types(props) {
  const variant = useVariant(props.variant);

  return (
    <Typography variant={variant}>
      Resize window to see text size changed
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Agreed. But my concern how to use it in declaring default props which are outside the component?

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari sorry I was in a hurry, updated my answer to include a possible solution.